# Share location same way as implemented in iOS Maps app

Tags: ios, location, maps, share

I would like to share my location in a "standardized" way.

How Apple Maps app shares the user's location is the benchmark for me. How can I share share the user's location like the Maps app does?

Answer (score 0):

Try following function.
I make one function to share my current location.

```
-(NSURL *)funSetGoogleMapImage :(NSString *)str IMAGE:(UIImageView *)imgViewBounds LAT:(NSString *)strlatitude LONG:(NSString *)strLongitude
{

    NSString *strImageResolution = @"";
    if (ScreenWidth == 414)
        strImageResolution = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.fx%.f",(imgViewBounds.bounds.size.width*3),imgViewBounds.bounds.size.height*3];
    else
        strImageResolution = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.fx%.f",(imgViewBounds.bounds.size.width*2),imgViewBounds.bounds.size.height*2];

//define pin
    NSString *strMarkerURl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon:%@..../ws/images/map_pin@2x.png",MapImage];


//Return image of current location mapp
    NSURL *ImgUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=%@,%@&markers=%@%@%@,%@&zoom=15&size=%@&scale=2&sensor=false",strlatitude,strLongitude,strMarkerURl,@"%7C",strlatitude,strLongitude,strImageResolution]];

    return ImgUrl;
}
```